# How to create subtotal in SQL with data from other table

Tags: sql, sum, subtotal

I'm trying to create subtotals for sales in different zip codes, since the invoice do not have zip codes I need to get it from the customer table.

Here is my sql that will show all the transactions:

```
select c.name, c.zip, i.total, i.salestax from customer c, invoice i
where i.sdate >= '2019-09-01' and i.sdate <= '2019-09-30' and 
c.accountnum=i.customernr
order by c.zip
```

I tried to add SUM to total and salestax, but if I do that I get an SQL error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
KHJ

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `join` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your query, you can use `sum() and group-by` to get your result

```
select c.name, c.zip, sum(i.total) as total, sum(i.salestax) as tax
from  invoice i
inner join customer c on c.accountnum=i.customernr
group by c.zip, c.name
where i.sdate >= '2019-09-01' and i.sdate <= '2019-09-30' 
order by c.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want totals by zip code, then that should be the only key you are grouping by.  And then you need aggregation functions:

```
select c.zip, sum(i.total), sum(i.salestax)
from customer c join
     invoice i
     on c.accountnum = i.customernr
where i.sdate >= '2019-09-01' and i.sdate <= '2019-09-30' 
group by c.zip
order by c.zip
```

Comment: Thanks, join has always been a mystery to me.

Comment: @KimHJ . . . Your question suggests that you want one row per zip code.  If so, then this is the more correct answer.  If you want one row per name and zip code, then metal's is more correct.